# Removing the space between the input field and button in a search bar

Tags: css

I am currently trying to modify a default search bar in an application and it seems that I have the option to write a CSS file to customize the search bar. My problem is that by default, the search button and the input field has a space between them when they shouldn't. I am not sure what is causing this, but I am trying to fix it in CSS.

My search bar looks like this now:

[image: current search bar]

When in fact it should be like this:

[image: desired output]

My CSS code is this for now:

```
.main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .sidebar-form {
  border: none;
  display:inline-block; 
}

.main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .sidebar-form .input-group {
  font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  border:none;
}

.main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .sidebar-form .input-group-btn {
  border:none;
}
```

I tried to eliminate the margin, padding, everything, but nothing seems to work (and I don't know CSS too well either to figure it out).

Thank you.

Comment: In future, please include the relevant HTML as well. It provides important context for CSS.

Comment: @JonP Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I realized that later. When I wrote the post I didn't have access to it (or more accurate, I didn't exactly know where to find it since I am writing the app in R) but later I just went to the browser version of the app and used "Inspect code" which also was the moment  when I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the input-group-btn or input-group-text(made-up name for search textarea) has non-zero margins between them, so make them zero, and try enclosing them in a div and then apply same margins for the enclosing div.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am seeing that both the button and the search field are enclosed in a div already (input-group), so I tried to apply the properties to it but still no result. `.main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .sidebar-form {
  font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
}

.main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .sidebar-form .input-group{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}`

Comment: Do margin:0 for only input-group-btn class and input-group-text (assumed name for search text)

Comment: Also! force apply your changes by adding "!important" after the margin: 0

Comment: I did a mistake, instead of modifying the actual button I was applying these modifications to a container of the button. I set the margins to 0 and everything looks good now. Thank you so so much for the help!

Comment: @KaranBhagat , no **[do not use !important](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used)** . If the style is not being applied, use a more specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is a little late but:

if you apply `display: flex;` to the container that agroup the search bar and the button remove the space betwwen the elements!